# Javascript: Labeling array results

Tags: javascript, arrays

Alright so here is my Html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Planning</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Function.js"></script>  
    </head>
        <body>

        <form id="form">

            <h1><b>Please enter data</b></h1>
        <hr size="3"/>
        <br>

            <label for="Name">Name:</label> <input id="Name" type="text" /> 
        <br>

            <label for="Date">Date:   </label><input id="Date" type="text" />
        <br>

            <label for="Plans">Plans: </label><input id="Plans" type="text" />
        <br>
        <br>

            <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="insert();">
            <input type="button" value="Show data" onclick="show();"> <br>

            <h2><b>Data:</b></h2>
        <hr>
        </form>

        <div id="display">

            </div>
        </body>

</html>
```

And my Javscript:

```
    var Name=new Array();
    var Date=new Array();
    var Plans=new Array();

    function insert(){
        var NameValue = document.getElementById('Name').value;
        var DateValue = document.getElementById('Date').value;
        var PlansValue = document.getElementById('Plans').value;
        Name[Name.length]=NameValue;
        Date[Date.length]=DateValue;
        Plans[Plans.length]=PlansValue;
      }

    function show() {
      var content="<b>Your Plans For the Day:</b><br>";
      var Namelabel ="<p>Name</p>"
      for(var i = 0; i < Name.length; i++) {
         + Namelabel;
         content +=Name[i]+"<br>";
      }
      for(var i = 0; i < Date.length; i++) {
         content +=Date[i]+"<br>";
      }
      for(var i = 0; i < Plans.length; i++) {
         content +=Plans[i]+"<br>";
      }
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = content;
    }
```

The code on its own works fine but what I for the life of me can't figure out how to do is add a label identifying what the data showed is.

example being "Name:" for the displayed names and "dates:" appearing before the displayed dates.

I have other parts of the document I need to do in the meantime but this is really bothering me.

Comment: You mean like `content += "Name: " + Name[i] + "<br>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you show function to this

```
function show() {
      var content="<b>Your Plans For the Day:</b><br>";
      for(var i = 0; i < Name.length; i++) {
         content += "Name " + Name[i]+"<br>";
      }
      for(var i = 0; i < Date.length; i++) {
         content += "Date" + Date[i]+"<br>";
      }
      for(var i = 0; i < Plans.length; i++) {
         content += "Plans" + Plans[i]+"<br>";
      }
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = content;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I thought I already tried this but I must of missed something.